# SASS in Sinatra: couldn't set custom directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, sass, rack

I've read [Sinatra SASS custom directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268366/sinatra-sass-custom-directory) and [Sinatra custom SASS directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285777/sinatra-custom-sass-directory) .

But it doesn't work for me. I write this app:

```rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'sass'
require 'slim'

configure do
    set :views, :scss => 'assets/css' 
end

get '/css/*.css' do
    scss params[:splat].first.to_sym
end

get '/' do
    slim :index
end
```

When I'm running it I get a error:

```
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
TypeError at /css/style.css
no implicit conversion of Hash into String
```

Comment: The error is coming from your CSS/SASS file. Does it say what line the implicit conversion is happening on? Can you show the relevant CSS section?

Comment: be careful with a to_sym conversion. That leaves your app open to dos because invalid css file requests (404) all create a symbol which are never garbage collected. Check for the file first before you create a symbol.

`# sass style sheet generation
get '/css/:file.css' do
  halt 404 unless File.exist?("views/#{params[:file]}.scss")
  time = File.stat("views/#{params[:file]}.scss").ctime
  last_modified(time)
  scss params[:file].intern
end`

Comment: sorry, looks awful. Here's the proper gist: http://j.mp/19r6REE

Comment: @ArmanH, the file assets/css/style.sass is just
`h1 { color: #ff0000; }`

Comment: Are you're using SCSS instead of SASS, which is supposed to be formatted with indentation, not brackets? Try changing the syntax to proper SASS to see if makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's vice versa, first `:scss` symbol and then `:views`:

```rb
configure do
  set :scss, :views => 'assets/css'
end
```